# I made a reflecting texure but the objects are not reflecting in the texture. How can i fix that?

Tags: texturing

[image: This is the image]

I made a reflecting texure but the objects are not reflecting in the texture. How can i fix that?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128162/how-do-the-new-light-probes-in-eevee-work/128164#128164 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123164/what-is-lookdev-mode-for-in-2-8/123168#123168 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132945/eevee-ignores-light-emission-outside-of-the-camera-frame/133060#133060

Comment: In blender 2.80 the default render engine is EEVEE (instead of cycles). So that is why you need the links posted by the previous commenter.

Comment: Please mind the terminology. It is important in this area, words that are synonyms in natural language might mean different things in CG jargon and it sometimes might get really hard to communicate really quickly if you don't put effort into it. Textures cannot be reflective. Materials or shaders can be reflective and materials can have textures that define their properties. Textures or texture maps or image maps can define things like the amount of reflections or the sharpness/roughness of them  or even what is reflected, but do not reflect anything themselves as shaders or materials do.

Comment: sorry material.